# How to change product thumbnail size when nothing works in woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, woocommerce, size

Problem:
Thumbnails in my shop are generated very tiny (about 240). I want to make them bigger.
https://minister.deploy-test.co/sklep/

-Changing their size via woocommerce settings do not affect them.
-There is no theme settings for that.
-Using third party plugin for thumbnails regnerate do not affect at all.

Somewhere there there is some fuction which tells during upload to make copy of photo as tiny and use it. Can anybody please point me where to edit to force this theme to make and use bigger product thumbnails in shop section?

Thanks in advance! And sorry that I ask so simple question for you code experts but litrally there is nobody else to ask. So .. thanks! :)

PD

Comment: From your theme documentation - http://document.g5plus.net/hebes/#Woocommerce-Settings  - Go to Appearance → Customize. Click on Woocommerce → Product Images tab. Then setup Product Images options.

Comment: Thanks @MartinMirchev. It doesn't work. I set there 900 px as thumb size and regenerated thumbnails. Still some fuction from theme overwrites that and keeps thumbs as 240/260 and around pix.

Comment: Then contact your theme author for solution since its premium theme.

Comment: I will. Usually it takes days / weeks that's why I asked here. Thanks.